# How do I stop Microsoft ML server on linux?

Tags: windows, microsoft-r

I have Microsoft's Machine Learning server (formally revolution analytics) running on Ubuntu 16.04 . I started it with `/opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.3.0/bin/R/activate.sh` but [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/install/machine-learning-server-linux-install) doesn't provide a way of stopping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this command:

`sudo -i az ml admin node stop --computenode --webnode`